# validating users in jquery using php

Tags: php, jquery, sql

I have a users table that includes a column name called "roles".
I want to select the details of the user where the column name "roles" is "admin"
and show a button only admin can see

my jquery code is as below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    load_comment();
    function load_comment() {// show comment function
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "code.php",
            data: {
                't_id' : <?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>,
                'comment_load_data': true
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $('.comment-container').html("");
                // console.log(response);
                $.each(response, function (key, value) {
                        $('.comment-container').
                            append('<div class="reply_box border p-2 mb-2">\
                            <h6 class="border-bottom d-inline">  '+value.user['username'] +' | '+value.cmt['time'] +' </h6>\
                            <p class="para"> '+value.cmt['comment'] +' </p>\
                            <button value="'+value.cmt['ID'] +'" class="badge btn-warning reply_btn">Reply</button>\
                            <button id="view" value="'+value.cmt['ID'] +'" class="badge btn-danger view_reply_btn">View Replies</button>\
                            <?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE role = 'admin';"; $result = $con->query($sql);if ($result->num_rows > 0) {while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {if  ($row["role"] == "admin"){ echo "<button>Delete</button>";}}}?>\
                            <div class="ml-4 reply_section"></div>\
                            </div>\
                    ');
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

The sql query is working fine in PHPMyAdmin but the button is not shown when I logged in as a admin
This script is included in a PHP file

Comment: What is not working? Do you get an error-message or an exception of some kind?

Comment: This again. Do you get any errors? Forgot to include a php file? Where is `$con` set in your script?

Comment: Please format your code properly and don't write multiple PHP statements after each other in one line. That makes it _way_ harder to read.

Comment: If so how do I get to fix this code I'm quite new to jquery sorry...

Comment: _Side note:_ Your PHP code also has some unnecessary fluff, like the `if ($row["role"] == "admin")`-statement. Since you're only fetching records where `role` is equal to `admin`, you already know that the `role` is equal to `admin`. It will also add a `delete`-button for each record you get back. If you have 4 users that are admin in the database, your PHP code will output 4 delete buttons after each other.

Comment: _"and show a button only admin can see"_ - but your query there has no connection whatsoever to the actual current user ...? All you are doing there, is read _all_ records with `role=admin` from your database.

Answer (score 0):

So you'll need to check if the current user is an admin. As [M. Eriksson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2453432/m-eriksson) mentioned your current code will get all users with the `admin` role and print a delete button for each user found.

What you actually need to do is get the current users role and check if that it matches admin. Assuming the current user ID accessible somewhere in your code you could start by doing a query something like...

```php
<?php
    // CHANGE THIS TO YOUR CURRENT USER ID
    $current_user_id = 1; // maybe get_current_user_id() ??

    $statement = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?");
    $statement->bind_param('i', $current_user_id);
    $statement->execute();
    
    // User specific variables
    $user = $statement->fetch_assoc();
    $is_admin = ($user['role'] ?? null) === 'admin';
?>
```

Once you have the above variables you can do something like...

```js
// Create JS variables. (We print boolean values with `json_encode`).
const userIsAdmin = <?= json_encode($is_admin); ?>;
const postId = <?= (int)$_GET['id']; ?>;

(function($) {

    const $container = $('.comment-container');

    // Make ajax request.
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'code.php',
        data: {
            t_id: postId,
            comment_load_data: true
        },
        success: function (response) {

            // Empty the container, for some reason it might have contents already ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
            $container.empty();

            // Loop through each comment.
            $.each(response, function (key, value) {

                const comment = data?.cmt;
                const author = data?.user;

                // Create a comment box.
                const $commentBox = $('<div>', {
                    class: 'reply_box border p-2 mb-2'
                }).appendTo($container);

                // Give the reply a title (and add it to the comment box).
                $('<h6>', {
                    class: 'border-bottom d-inline',
                    text: `${user['username']} | ${comment['time']}`
                }).appendTo($commentBox);

                // Print the comment (and add it to the comment box).
                $('<p>', {
                    class: 'para',
                    text: comment['comment']
                }).appendTo($commentBox);

                // Create a reply button (and add it to the comment box).
                $('<button>', {
                    class: 'badge btn-warning reply_btn',
                    value: comment['ID'],
                    type: 'button',
                    text: 'Reply'
                }).appendTo($commentBox);

                // Create a view button (and add it to the comment box).
                $('<button>', {
                    class: 'badge btn-danger view_reply_btn',
                    value: comment['ID'],
                    type: 'button',
                    text: 'View Replies'
                }).appendTo($commentBox);

                // Only create a delete button if the user is an admin.
                if (userIsAdmin) {
                    $('<button>', {
                        class: 'badge btn-danger delete_btn',
                        value: comment['ID'],
                        type: 'button',
                        text: 'Delete'
                    }).appendTo($commentBox); // (and add it to the comment box)
                }

                // Now add this empty div for something?
                $('<div>', {
                    class: 'ml-4 reply_section'
                }).appendTo($commentBox);

            });
        }
    });

    // Reply button event.
    $container.on('click', 'button.reply_btn', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const $button = $(this);
        const commentId = $button.attr('value');
        // Do something...
    });

    // View button event.
    $container.on('click', 'button.view_reply_btn', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const $button = $(this);
        const commentId = $button.attr('value');
        // Do something...
    });

    // Delete button event.
    $container.on('click', 'button.delete_btn', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const $button = $(this);
        const commentId = $button.attr('value');
        // Do something...
    });

})(jQuery);
```

One thing to note that you will want to double check the user is an admin on the server side when processing the delete action. Simply hiding the button client side isn't good enough.